# Is it better to grep locally or remotely?

Tags: linux, perl, file, ssh, grep

I often log-in in a series of servers to grep for something in the logs.
I thought to automate this via a script to make it easier.
So my question is which approach is most efficient and sensible?
Doing

```
my @data = `ssh host grep pattern logfile`
```

Or download the file locally (scp the file) and do the grep locally?

Comment: You are asking if it is faster to first download the file and grep locally, or to execute the grep command on the remote host and just transferring the result to your script?

Comment: @GhostGambler:No. The grep will be automatic. Either I do ssh + grep OR scp + grep inside my script

Comment: @Jim: I think your answer should be *yes*. You can *"first download the file and grep locally"* (`scp` + `grep` inside your script) or *"execute the grep command on the remote host and just [transfer] the result"* (`ssh` + `grep`)

Answer (score 5):

That depends on

- what percentage of log lines the `grep` filters
- the available CPU (remotely and locally)
- the available bandwidth for the `scp`
- the available filesystem size
- whether you may need the original logfile for other purposes subsequently

If you don't need the file later, and if doing the remote `grep` is not a problem, reducing the data before they are sent over the network (which is typically the bottleneck) is beneficial most of the time.

To further reduce the travelling data you can even do something like

```
my @data = `ssh host 'grep pattern logfile | gzip' | gunzip`
```

This should be mostly equivalent, for your purposes, to

```
my @data = `ssh -C host 'grep pattern logfile'`
```

although I have never tried this one.

BTW, you said you use `egrep`, which is fine, but I never get tired reminding people that `grep` interprets dots as wildcards, and therefore `fgrep` (or `grep -F`) should be used for fixed strings.

Comment: 1)Actually I am planning to use egrep 2) I don't really need the logs subsequently 3) For the rest I am not sure about them to be honest

Comment: Agree that it all depends, but I think it's safe to say that generally, it will be faster to do the grep on a remote machine, avoiding the "cost" of retrieving the file, because networks are usually slower that direct file access by an order of magnitude. Good luck to all.

Comment: @shellter, I saw your comment immediately after editing my answer for that :-)

Comment: @shellter:The "Good luck" does it imply I am overlooking problems?

Comment: @WalterTross:The `gunzip` is supposed to happen locally?

Comment: No, "good luck to all" is my way of signifying to everyone that I wish them well in their endeavors, but in a way that is understandable by all that can speak even a little english :-)

Comment: @WalterTross: A list of *"depends on"* is much less useful without an explanation of the dependencies.

Comment: @Jim: yes, the output of `ssh` with 2 arguments (sorry, I had a typo there, which I have fixed now) is piped into `gunzip` (and sorry for the late reply, I was driving...)

Comment: `ssh` can use compression so there may be little reason to use `gzip`

Comment: @BradGilbert: right. I mentioned `ssh -C` last only for (a) clarity (b) lack of experience with it. I've always transferred logfiles that had been gzipped beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

The `grep` won't be *"automatic"*: it has to be performed by a computer somewhere.

The obvious answer is that it is best to do it remotely, because that way (potentially) fewer lines of data must be returned via the network. That is, unless the remote machine is so very slow that it is quicker to network the unwanted data than to filter it out.

Why don't you benchmark it to compare the two options? And don't start to optimise until you have things working well.

Comment: `Why don't you benchmark it to compare the two options?` I thought that this might be a common problem and there might be a common practice or sensible approach.This is a utility not to ship to production for customers.Hence I am interested in making a sensible approach for users which are developers

Comment: @Jim: There isn't a general answer that covers all configurations. You have the chance to experiment and record something here that will help others in the future. Try both ways and post what you find, with as much information as possible about the systems at each end, and the nature and speed of the link.

Comment: @Jim if this is a utility then you have to be aware that not all systems have a `grep` utility that you can call.

Answer (score 0):

If you use java you can simply use [grep4j](https://code.google.com/p/grep4j/) library, otherwise if you want something graphical you can use [SSearcH Everywhere](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ssearcheverywhere/?source=directory)